# Is there a way to identify that IIS or the website had been stopped?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, appfabric

I have a WCF Service that I am hosting on AppFabric with IIS 7.5 and Windows 2008. The service is set to auto start as recommended.
When the service starts it goes into a while loop that never ends, keep in mind that this is the desired behavior.
The while loop is supposed to process some data that I don't know when its going to be available.

The problem is when I shut down the website, or IIS, the service keeps running. So my questions are:
Is there a way to identify that IIS or the website had been stopped?
Is there a better way of achieving this never ending behavior?

Hopefully there is enough information here.

Comment: What does the while loop do? Why do you need to have one? This information will be helpful for an answer.

Comment: Maybe host in a Windows Service?

Comment: Along with usr's question: Why would you want a service to loop forever?  It seems...wrong.

Comment: Service in a loop is like a loop within a loop

Comment: If the service is working in an AppPool, there is a host w3wp.exe process (which is IIS working process).

Comment: I have edited the description, but the idea, is that I don't know when data is available, and when it is, I should process it as fast as I can. So thats why a loop. "Is there data? Is there data? Is there data? Is there data?"

Comment: Sergey, the fact that I shut down IIS and the service keep running, makes me believe, that the AppPool has no dependency on the process, so it must be all under AppFabric.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have an infinite polling loop running. This design might well make sense, although it is unusual.

I recommend that you start a separate thread which does the polling. Your threads code should look like this:

```
void ThreadProc() {
 try {
  while(true) { ... }
 }
 catch (ThreadAbortException) {
  //AppDomain shutdown
 }
}
```

When shutting down all threads will be aborted. This is the trick to detect shutdown.

Start the thread like this:

```
new Thread(ThreadProc) { IsBackground = true }
```

Comment: I will try this approach, but here is some thought, I don't think there is ever a ThreadAbortException, I believe that the service is hosted on AppFabric entirely and IIS is just a host of some sort, so killing IIS never trigger any error, or odd behavior on the app, and maybe there is an event that I can hookup to that will help me with that.

Comment: If your hosting process gets killed there is no event to be received. The process is *gone*. In this case you just can't receive a notification.

Answer (score 0):

In regards with the Web Site status detection question: If you know the site name, you can use [Microsoft.Web.Administration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to determine if the site has been started or not. Some good examples are available on [Learn IIS website](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/)

However, I second others concern here as to why you are using an infinite loop...

Comment: As I have stated I am open for suggestions, but the reason is that I am doing polling to know when to process pieces of data. The service actually contacts another services that I do not own, so I don't know when it has been used.

Comment: I see. So somebody calls your service and it in response contacts that other service, correct? If so, why do you need to infinitely wait for something? The whole point of using WCF seems to handle web requests and process data when the request arrives... Am I missing anything? Regardless, you should be able to detect whether a site is up or not using the Microsoft.Web.Administration API above.

Comment: The service behaves like a windows service, its supposed to be the same exact thing, but instead of a Windows Service I am using "APPFABRIC", with WCF. So no, nobody calls it, it supposed to be self sufficient, be running at all times, polling the data waiting for proper information to be found then some processing happens.